# How to disregard a row in a returned MS Access query when all fields bar one are distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create a query on Access 2010 which only produces a single row per patient. There are a really small number of patients (each patient represented by

a unique nhs_number in the table n) who are listed as having 2 practices in the table pp and so two rows are generated for them.  Is there a way I can arbitrarily select one of the practices and ignore the other?
This is the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    n.nhs_number,
    IIF(ch.care_home_date>#2/1/1900#, "TRUE", "FALSE") AS care_home,
    pp.practice

FROM (nhs_no_tbl AS n 
        LEFT JOIN patient_practice_tbl AS pp ON n.nhs_number = pp.nhs_number)
        LEFT JOIN patient_care_home_tbl AS ch ON n.nhs_number = ch.nhs_number;
```

The tables the query is using contains data along these lines:

```
nhs_no_tbl:
|nhs_number|
| -------- |
|1         |
|2         |
|3         |
|4         |
```

patient_practice_tbl:

```
|nhs_number|practice|
| -------- | ------ |
|1         |GP_A    |
|2         |GP_A    |
|3         |GP_B    |
|4         |GP_A    |
|4         |GP_B    |
```

patient_care_home_tbl:

```
|nhs_number|care_home_date|
| -------- | ------------ |
|1         |1/5/2000      |
|1         |1/10/2010     |
|4         |26/10/2017    |
```

At the end, I'd like the query to return the following:

```
|nhs_number|Care_home|practice|
| -------- | ------- | ------ |
|1         |TRUE     |GP_A    |
|2         |FALSE    |        |
|3         |FALSE    |        |
|4         |TRUE     |GP_A [or GP_B]  |
```

Comment: If you want a single row per patient, then I would expect `group by patientid` or something like that.  Without sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing, a more detailed answer is really not possible.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.  I've edited my original post to give that information, and a stripped down form of the query that I hope gets to the essence of what I'm after a little more.  I didn't think I could use Group by without an aggregate function?  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've update the query with CTE,

```
;WITH cte1 AS ---select all results
(
    SELECT DISTINCT nnt.nhs_number,
    CASE WHEN pcht.care_home_date IS NULL 
         THEN 'FALSE'
         ELSE 'TRUE'
    END AS CareHome,
    ppt.practice,
    rank()OVER(PARTITION BY nnt.nhs_number ORDER BY ppt.practice) AS R 
    FROM #nhs_no_tbl nnt
    LEFT JOIN #patient_practice_tbl ppt ON nnt.nhs_number = ppt.nhs_number
    LEFT JOIN #patient_care_home_tbl pcht ON nnt.nhs_number = pcht.nhs_number
),
CTE2 AS  ---choose who may have multiple pracices
(
    SELECT nhs_number
    FROM CTE1
    WHERE R = 2
),
CTE3 AS --- combine GP_A and GP_B
(
    SELECT t.nhs_number,STRING_AGG(val,',') AS Practices
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT val = cte1.practice, CTE1.nhs_number 
        FROM #nhs_no_tbl nnt 
        INNER JOIN CTE2 ON nnt.nhs_number = CTE2.nhs_number 
        INNER JOIN cte1 ON nnt.nhs_number = CTE1.nhs_number
    ) t
    --RIGHT JOIN #nhs_no_tbl nnt ON t.nhs_number = nnt.nhs_number
    GROUP BY t.nhs_number
)
SELECT cte1.nhs_number,cte1.carehome,cte1.practice, cte3.Practices
FROM CTE1 
LEFT JOIN cte3 ON cte1.nhs_number = CTE3.nhs_number
```

The result would be

[image]

then next you could store the result into a temp table and update temp table where practices is not null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JiachengGao. Actually, the care home section of the code is working already; where I'm struggling is to find code that pulls over patient_practice_tbl,nhs_number only once, even if there are two entries sharing the same ID.  4 appears twice in the table, with GP_A and GP_B, but I want to select just one of those rows with this query.  If you have any ideas, that's great.  Otherwise, thank you anyway for taking the time.

Comment: @Zierspargel hey there, I've edited, please check, thx